# Why is the question about maladaptive thought deleted without migrated?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration, deleted-questions, flagging

[Is there any study about how half-baked philosophies encourage maladaptive thoughts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57006/19487) (deleted)

At first I flagged the question to migrate it to Psychology, and it was closed without being migrated. Then I flagged to understand why, and then it got deleted and still not being migrated. All my flags are rated helpful, but still I don't know why it isn't migrated or is worth deleted. Can you explain?

[Flagged Posts for Ooker - Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/19487):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooker. I have undeleted the question and apologise that your request for migration was not acted on. I suggest that in view of the cumulative delay in my contacting Psychology mods, waiting for a reply, and if and when I receive one then informing you, it might be best for you to post your question directly on the Psychology site. The Psychology mods will either accept the question (end of story) or tell you why they can't accept it.

I am unable leave the question on PSE but in undeleting it temporarily I'm enabling you to copy it across to Psychology. I can give you two days to do this.

I hope this is a satisfactory reply and that Psychology will take your question & that it will attract helpful replies. The question plainly matters to you; and it matters to me that it should be in the best place to receive useful responses.

Best - Geoffrey Thomas

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have reasked it [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21140/12937). As first I was quite surprised for getting the question deleted, and I did some research. Long story short, here's my proposal in Meta SE: [If questions are closed as being too broad or unclear, should they not be deleted too quick?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318329/260800)

Comment: My apologies for our unresponsiveness. I pretty much always respond to summons in the teacher's lounge - but this question was not brought t my attention. There are three other mods on Psych&Neurosci and I doubt all of us decided not to react, and again, I haven't seen any summons on this Q. How did the mod team from Philosophy try to contact us?

Comment: I also don't see any indication of a contact attempt anywhere...

Comment: I apologise that I did not contact. My assumption was that the questioner would her/ himself apply to Psy with the question without my going through a mediation process. I now understand the procedures and the problem will not happen again. I don't suggest and never have suggested that Psy did not respond to a contact. Best : GLT.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the mod who deleted the question, so I can only give a partial answer:

The usual process for mods, if they are asked to migrate or think it in order themselves, is asking the mods of the receiving community whether they think the question appropriate as it is or at least mendable to become a good fit.

Depending on the answer (if there ever happens to be one), the migration is enacted or declined, where in the latter case there should be a short comment explaining the unsuitability for migration.

I cannot specify whether such a process has happened in this case, but I know from another question that it is possible that the Psychology.SE mods did not answer at all.

Comment: Is the asking process required for any migration? (Why) can't you check whether it has happened or not?

Comment: @Ooker: It is not *required*, it is etiquette, since otherwise, we would have network-wide migration-deletion processes (you cannot imagine what people think suitable for Philosophy.SE *at face value*!) with mods getting mad at each other. There have been cases of questions "bouncing" between sites with re-re-re-re-re-...-migration. Also, I cannot (or would not like to) track the actions of fellow mods in the detail needed to fully answer this question. You will have to wait for an answer of his.

Comment: Same comment as above - feel free to delete - My apologies for our unresponsiveness. I pretty much always respond to summons in the teacher's lounge - but this question was not brought t my attention. There are three other mods on Psych&Neurosci and I doubt all of us decided not to react, and again, I haven't seen any summons on this Q. How did the mod team from Philosophy try to contact us?

Comment: @AliceD. Unintentionally I failed to respond to the request for migration. I take full responsibility for this. I have as you will have seen apologised to the OP and  suggested how to put the situation right. In future I will follow the inter-mod procedures. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas - No worries whatsoever, we're just humans sacrificing our time to moderate :) Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: @AliceD actually the bit "from another question" that makes me assume that this happened before. "Another" means "not this question"